# Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long)

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, json-deserialization

I need to deserialize the following JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":0,
      "serial_number":"M501000003",
      "partner_account":{  
         "id":8
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "serial_number":"M501000004",
      "partner_account":{  
         "id":8
      }
   }
]
```

But I get the error

> Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=8, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator,scope=com.dev.service.entities.PartnerAccount.

I'm trying to save a list of objects to the db. I know there's already a similar question but that didn't help me, it didn't have any steps to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422838/jsonmappingexception-already-had-pojo-for-id

Comment: That didn't help, I'm already using the scope parameter and still get the error.

Comment: Add your code so that we can understand what is wrong.

Comment: Could you show your `POJO` classes?